# Why does Word add an indent that I can't delete?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I try writing a sentence that overflows onto a new line, word generates a tab that can be seen in shown indents, but cannot be deleted? How can I fix this?

Comment: Whenever word is indenting something incorrectly, I go up to the ruler and slide the corresponding elements where I want them.

Comment: didn't work, at least not for me.

Answer (score 1):

That indent is called the Hanging indent, and you can set it to 0 in Paragraph settings, which is accessible by clicking the more settings button of the Paragraph group in the Home tab:

[image: 1]

You can also change it by dragging the indent marker on the ruler (as Appleoddity mentioned). Make sure you drag the marker that looks like a triangle with its point pointing up, and *not* the square marker that it's attached to:

[image: diagram]